# Compartilhamento via UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver o problema chamado: 
"*LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called*" apresenta sempre que pressiono um determinado `BarButtonItem`, segue abaixo o trecho do código em SWIFT.

```
@IBAction func btShared(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

   let myActivity: UIActivityViewController =    
   UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)

   myActivity.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard]

   self.presentViewController(myActivity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao construir um `UIActivityViewController` tens que indicar uma lista NÃO nula como primeiro argumento `activityItems`. Tem que conter pelo menos um item.

#### Exemplo:

```
let someText:String = textView.text
let google:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://google.com/")

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [someText, google],
        applicationActivities: nil)

self.navigationController.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

#### Editado: para evitar o erro (Objective-C)

Adicionar após o `presentViewController`:

```
if ([activityVC respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)])
{
    // iOS 8+
    UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = [activityVC popoverPresentationController];

    presentationController.sourceView = sender; //Se for botão, alternativa: self.view
}
```

Comment: Ola Ricardo, o erro ainda persiste, ao executar o Action BarButtonItem, continua apresentando a mensagem de erro: LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called

Comment: Pelos vistos trata-se de um bug da Apple: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1049415#1049415